# Generating PDF files in the basis of MS Office documents in Web App

Tags: xml, web-services, jakarta-ee, pdf, pdf-generation

Problem:

I have a set of documents (templates) written by marketing guys like manuals, license agreements or advertising materials that can be saved in one of the formats supported by MS Office 2007. During a WS request I have to modify the content of the documents (e.g. fill up empty fields) and generate PDF files in the basis of them.

The problem is my company uses Apache™ FOP which force me to write some home made XMLs more or less like this one

```
<section>
   <header>Regulamin</header>
   <content>
     <numbered-list>
      <list-item>Bla bla <caption>bold something</caption></list-item>
     </numbered-list>
   </content>
</section>
```

then this is filled up and transformed by using XSLT to XSL-FO and then finally this is converted to PDF. The real pain is that I have to manually convert Word docs to XMLs.

Does anyone know a better way to deal with generation of PDF in the basis of Word documents ?

Comment: You could store WordML/Word's XML format and write code that substitutes the information in that file. Then possibly use RenderX's WordML to XSL FO conversion. http://www.renderx.com/tools/word2fo.html . However, I can tell you this does things that Apache FOP does not support.

Comment: One question ... do the changes you make effect the flow of the document in any way? Or are all the changes you make are stamping data on top of a fixed document in absolute positions?

Comment: Mostly there are fixed fields like dates, clients' details, addresses, but I have to be ready also to change a document flow for example if there was a license that could be different depends on a user requirements.

Answer (score 1):

As a commercial application my company did, you can examine this:

http://www.xportability.com/Software.xhtml

With the plug-in, you can open the Word documents in Word, add the fields from simple XML content you associate to this (now) template Word document. You export the template as an XSL which generates XSL FO.

Then you can combine XMLs from the user's submittals with that template to get new XSL FO for your engine to process to PDF.

Comment: looks like a good tool but actually is in beta version. Actually I have been looking for a stable long term solution :(

Comment: Comment accepted and welcome :) Truthfully the product itself was used as internal toolset for a services organization that creates template like those you mention as a service. For what you describe it is a breeze. It's beta because we have not gotten to a store front, final licensing mechanism and product-level user documentation. We've been busy. At any rate, you may have issues using FOP anyway, we do not test it as it falls down in too many areas to address.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I never tried this tool but [JODConverter sounds](http://shervinasgari.blogspot.cz/2010/05/automate-converting-of-documents-to-pdf.html) really promising, you can either run it from console (which might be useful to schedule some batch conversions) or directly from the Java code like

```
File inputFile = new File("document.doc");
File outputFile = new File("document.pdf");

// connect to an OpenOffice.org instance running on port 8100
OpenOfficeConnection connection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(8100);
connection.connect();

// convert
DocumentConverter converter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(connection);
converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile);

connection.disconnect();
```

Comment: sounds good the question is if I can modify the document somewhere in the middle

Comment: unfortunately: "In any case OpenOffice.org must be running as a service for JODConverter to work." :(